# Org-mode: customize link display

Tags: org-mode

I want to customize how a link is prettified.  Specifically, I want [Org-Ref](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref)'s cite links to display the bibiliography key.

A cite link looks like:

`[[cite:my-bib-key][pg. 2]]`

The default prettified display looks like:

`pg. 2`

How can I tweak org-mode to get this display instead:

`@my-bib-key: pg. 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a nice solution. I expanded this a bit here. It matches all the cite types and recolorizes the link. It doesn't do the manipulation to put @ and a space in, which can be done with the 'display property, but it add some complexity with extra managed properties that doesn't seem warranted to me.

```
(defun org-ref-make-org-link-cite-key-visible (&rest _)
  "Make the org-ref cite link visible in descriptive links."

  (save-match-data
    (let ((s (match-string 1))
      (beg (match-beginning 0))
      (end (match-end 0))
      (cite-re (format "^\\(%s:\\)"
               (regexp-opt (-sort
                    (lambda (a b)
                      (> (length a) (length b)))
                    org-ref-cite-types))))
      cite-type)

      (when (and s (string-match cite-re s))
    (setq cite-type (match-string 1 s))
    (remove-text-properties beg end
                '(invisible))
    (add-text-properties
     beg end
     `(face (:foreground ,org-ref-cite-color)))))))

(advice-add 'org-activate-bracket-links :after #'org-ref-make-org-link-cite-key-visible)
```

This has been pushed to org-ref, so it should be default behavior now. Thanks for sharing your approach!

Answer (score 2):

I have a mostly working version.  Org is pretty clever about how it fontifies
links.  It just hides the parts of the link when
`org-descriptive-links` is non-nil.  It does this using the
`buffer-invisibility-spec`.  The function that does all the heavy lifting is
`org-activate-bracket-links`

My solution is remove the `invisible` property from the cite-key part of the
URL by advising `org-activate-bracket-links`.

```
(defun my:make-org-link-cite-key-visible (&rest _)
  "Make the org-ref cite link visible in descriptive links."
  (when (string-prefix-p "cite:" (match-string 1))
    (remove-text-properties (+ (length "cite:") (match-beginning 1))
                            (match-end 1)
                            '(invisible))))

(advice-add 'org-activate-bracket-links :after #'my:make-org-link-cite-key-visible)
```

Unfortunately, there's no space between the key and the description so it looks
like:

`my-bib-keypg. 2`

I'll look at using text properties to fix that, but that's a decent bit of complexity.